# Scala test with play: guiceApplicationBuilder is not replacing application config with test config

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

I am transitioning from Java to Scala and trying to write some functional/regression tests. Although, initially, I am trying to fix some pre-existing tests as it seems when tests are running, they are using actual application.config instead of testApplication.conf.

**This is the way the way the tests are written:**

```
class ClientValidationTests extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite with MockitoSugar {

  val myConfigFile = new File("test/resources/testApplication.conf")
  val parsedConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(myConfigFile)
  val configuration = ConfigFactory.load(parsedConfig)

  override lazy val app: Application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    //.configure(Configuration.apply(ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("test/resources/testApplication.conf")).resolve()))
    .overrides(bind[Configuration].toInstance(Configuration(configuration)))
    .overrides(bind[ApprovalsClient].to[MockApprovalsClient])
    .overrides(bind[ClientDAO].to[MockClientDAO])
    .build()


  "The validation in the getListForClientWeb method for the web  service" must {
    "throw a UserNotPermittedForActionException when an client does not belong to the provided org" in {
      val clientWebService = app.injector.instanceOf[ClientWebService]
      val clientDao = app.injector.instanceOf[ClientDAO]


      val clientId = -1


      //Verify that mock dao routes do as expected
      clientDao.getId(clientId) mustBe List(-1)

    }
  }
}
```

This is the file structure where application.conf and testApplication.conf exists:

```
project-root
- app
  - conf
    -application.conf
- test
  - resources
    - testApplication.conf
```

**These are libararies being used here:**

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"




ivyScala := ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) }

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  //anorm dependency
  "com.typesafe.play"       %% "anorm"        % "2.5.3",
  "org.scalatestplus"       %% "play"         % "1.4.0-M4"  % "test",
  "org.mockito"              % "mockito-core" % "1.10.19"   % "test",
  "com.microsoft.sqlserver"  % "mssql-jdbc"   % "6.4.0.jre8"
)
```

Any insight?

Comment: Were you able to fix this ? I am also struggling with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can replace a real `conf/application.conf` with a `conf/application.test.conf` file by putting this in your sbt `build.sbt` file:

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf"
```

Comment: Does this work ? It is not working for me

Comment: Yes it works for me. In my `conf/application.test.conf` my first line of `conf/application.test.conf` is `include "application"` which imports the config from the main file which I then override where relevant.

Also note my test config file is in my conf directory, not `test/resources`.

Comment: I have tried both just to be sure ,  can you pls look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143111/scala-integration-test-not-picking-test-configuration?noredirect=1#comment130906291_74143111 
I will add more info about my conf files and what I tried