# Scala integration test not picking test configuration

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, scalatest

I want to write integration test cases in my scala project which uses play framework.
I am trying to instantiate a service class with all the dependecies like

```
class ATest extends AsyncFlatSpec with MockitoSugar{
  implicit val d = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
  implicit val tempEc = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))
  val logger = CustomLogger.getLogger(this.getClass.getCanonicalName)

  val testConfig = ConfigFactory.load("test.conf")
  val configuration = Configuration(testConfig)
  println(configuration.keys)
  val app1: Application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().configure(configuration).build
  val service =  Application.instanceCache[AService].apply(app1)
```

Issue that I am facing is , when I `println(configuration.keys)` correct keys from `test.conf` are printed but when `val service =  Application.instanceCache[DwSqsService].apply(app1)` is called it picks `application.conf` . Why is that ?

I even tried
`-Dconfig.resource=test.conf` flag. Still `application.conf` is picked. I am not able to find why this behaviour. Any idea ?

Adding more info:
have tried adding this into my build.sbt,
`javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf"` and `javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=test.conf"`

Also have tried using the command line
`sbt coverage test coverageReport -J-Xmx6g -Dconfig.file=test.conf`
This works it I bring my application up , but does not in tests

Comment: Where is your test conf file? How do you run your tests (SBT or IDE)? Also I'm not sure but I think Play looks for a file named "application.conf" not "test.conf".

Comment: Ah sorry, I read a by too fast. I believe the call to `configure` only overrides the values from "application.conf". You cannot prevent Play to load the application.conf.

Comment: test.conf file is in the same directory as application.conf. There is a way we can specify which config file to use and its by `-Dconfig.resource=` but only for tests its not working. 
Also test.conf has all the values that is needed to override if thats the case , still its not overriding.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a Sbt configuration to load your `test.conf` file when you're in Test mode.

```
Test / javaOptions ++= Seq("-Dconfig.resource=test.conf")
```

When your Play Java project run using `sbt test` it will load your `test.conf` that it's into `conf` folder.

Be aware that the code is to be used on Sbt 1.4+ version. If you're using older versions, you just need to adapt because older version uses other syntax (Maybe `javaOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Dconfig.resource=test.conf")` but I'm not sure.